# Java: How do I take input from a USB video capture device?

Tags: java, video-capture

I have a USB device that provides a video stream to the computer. Normally I just use a program to display this information in a window. I'd like to have my Java program take this image data directly into my code. How is this possible?

I already have drivers and everything set up. I just need to let my program access the data stream coming in through USB. I imagine this might be similar to using a USB webcam?

Comment: you want something like capturing video from webcam?

Comment: Yes, the device is similar to a webcam. It takes the yellow video cable of the 3-part RCA jack system. It converts this to video input for a computer through USB. It's like a webcam, but instead of having a photographic circuit to provide data, it uses a wire input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try [Xuggler](http://xuggle.com/)

its an open source wrapper for FFmpeg to get started with it look at [this java class](http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/java/xuggle-xuggler/src/com/xuggle/xuggler/demos/DecodeAndPlayAudioAndVideo.java) from the xuggler package
or this tutorial [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/xuggler-tutorial-transcoding-media.html)

or you could use the xuggler media tool .

The class i gave you link to should have anything you need to decode , play , and manipulate video from any source ... just change container.open(url...) change the URL to w.e source and it should work .

Here's an example project i once made with Xuggler :

[image: and example project i made with xuggler]

Comment: xuggle.com is offline.

Comment: when i posted the answer it was up Oo ... anyways here's a link for the jar http://xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/xuggle/xuggle-xuggler/5.4/xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of Xuggler. However I found out that OpenCV has built-in webcam input options. So I guess I won't be needing Xuggler! I'll keep it in mind for later though; I'm sure it'll come in handy for some future project.

Comment: a bit late but ... ive had good results with vlcJ too , actually changed the program above to using that since its more stable .